# can't use the "end" property of JSF 2.0 repeat tag's varStatus

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using the `repeat` tag of JSF 2.0 to loop through a list of objects and display some of their properties.  I want to use the `varStatus` attribute of `repeat` so that I can access the loop index, the number of the last list item, and to tell whether the end of the list has been reached (so the spacer won't be displayed).  I thought this would work:

```
<ui:repeat var="anObject" varStatus="repeatStatus" value="#{objectList}">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText value="Item #{repeatStatus.index + 1} of #{repeatStatus.end}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{anObject.text}" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText value="&nbsp;" rendered="#{false == repeatStatus.last}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

However, it never displays anything for `repeatStatus.end`.  The `index` and `last` properties work well.

Instead of `repeatStatus.end`, I tried using `objectList.size()`, but that worked for only the first item in the list.

How can I display the number of items in the list as part of the "Item x of y" text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end` is only used when you set the `size` attribute.

```html
<ui:repeat ... size="#{fn:length(objectList)}">
```

Alternatively, you can also just use it directly.

```html
Item #{repeatStatus.index + 1} of #{fn:length(objectList)}
```

By the way, the boolean comparison in `#{false == repeatStatus.last}` is ugly. It returns a boolean already; if you want to negate it, rather use `#{not repeatStatus.last}`.

Comment: That makes sense.  However, in this project I'm trying to avoid the use of JSTL.  

Based on your suggestion, I tried `size="#{objectList.size()}"`, but that had no effect.

Comment: Create a custom EL function then. I however don't see how that would be better than just using an existing JSTL function. Perhaps you're overgeneralizing the one and other as to "avoiding JSTL in JSF". Read this Q&A then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense As to `.size()`, that works only if your environment uses EL 2.2 or JBoss EL.

Comment: I've marked your answer as good even though I've not gotten it to work for me yet.  I've never seen one of your solutions that didn't work.  :)  I'm a Java newbie, so I'm not sure why it's not working, but I'll figure it out.  I verified what you said about the `size` attribute.  If I put a number in there, `repeatStatus.end` does show that number.  I began to think JSTL wasn't working, but then I tried `fn:toUpperCase` and that worked.  I think the evaluation of `objectList` is at fault.  I've had that problem before, but I think I need to open another question about that.

Comment: Also, a big thanks for pointing me to the "JSTL in JSF2" question.  I can't say I understand your answer completely, but I get the gist of it.  As I said, I'm new to Java and JSF, so I was going by the advice of my colleague on this project.  I think he was a little misinformed about this topic, too.

Comment: I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802782/make-jsf-2-0-evaluate-method-as-they-are-assigned-to-params-not-store-reference) about parameters being assigned method references rather than their results.  I feel like that's similar to the problem I have with getting `fn:length` to work.  It's like JSF doesn't see a value for `objectList` at the point that `fn:length(objectList)` is called.  `objectList` is supposed to be returned by a getter method.