# Make JSF 2.0 execute methods as they are assigned to params, not store reference to method?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Before I begin, my apologies if the wording of this question's title is confusing.  I hope my explanation here will make it much clearer.

In a JSF template of my application, I want to include another template and pass a parameter to it that holds the results of an application method.  In this parent template, I have:

```
<ui:repeat var="loopObject" value="#{ApplicationBean.objectList}">
    <ui:include src="anotherTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="firstParam" 
            value="#{ApplicationBean.initForOtherTemplate(loopObject)}" />
    </ui:include>
</ui:repeat>
```

It turns out, though, that `initForOtherTemplate` is not executed at this point and `firstParam` contains a reference to that method, rather than its return value, as I expected.

Actually, while `initForOtherTemplate` does have a return value, `anotherTemplate.xhtml` doesn't need it.  However,the method does set up some other objects in `ApplicationBean` that this new template will use.  For example, it sets values for `importantInfo` and `importantInfoToo`, which the other template needs.

`anotherTemplate.xhtml` contains:

```
<ui:remove>
    <!-- 
    When a parameter contains a method call, the method isn't executed until
    the parameter is referenced.  So we reference the parameter here and ignore
    the results.  There must be a better way.
    -->
</ui:remove>
<h:outputText value="#{firstParam}" style="display: none;" />
<h:outputText value="#{ApplicationBean.importantInfo}" />
<h:outputText value="#{ApplicationBean.importantInfoToo}" />
```

If this template didn't reference `firstParam`, then `importantInfo` and `importantInfoToo` wouldn't be set or have unpredictable values.  This is very disappointing, because I expected `initForOtherTemplate` to be executed in the parent template, rather than here, which feels messy.

How can I get the assignment of the parameter to actually execute the method immediately rather than store a reference to it?

Answer (score 3):

The `<ui:repeat>` is an `UIComponent` which runs during view render time. The `<ui:include>` is a `TagHandler` (like JSTL) which runs during view build time. So at the moment `<ui:include>` runs, the `<ui:repeat>` isn't running and thus the `#{loopObject}` isn't available in the EL scope at all.

Replacing `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>` should solve this particular problem.

```html
<c:forEach var="loopObject" items="#{ApplicationBean.objectList}">
    <ui:include src="anotherTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="firstParam" 
            value="#{ApplicationBean.initForOtherTemplate(loopObject)}" />
    </ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) - Substitute "JSTL" with "ui:include".

Comment: Thanks!  It make a lot of sense, but I'm running into other problems.  If I try this with a list of one object, all is well.  As soon as I try two objects or more, I get a NullPointerException.  I'm having a hell of a time figuring out what's null.

Comment: Having the stacktrace would be helpful as that gives a detailed insight as to what's happening in the code.

Comment: I think I'm getting close.  I've got it narrowed down, at least.  I found that the null pointer exception was happening in the method I call in the `ui:param` tag.  It seems that some of the other code in the app is changing `objectList` in the middle of the loop.  I need to find out where and why.  The strange thing is that this problem never appeared until after I changed `ui:repeat` for `c:forEach`.

Comment: I had given your answer the green check-mark earlier, just after I resolved my null pointer problem.  However, after I re-enabled some code that I had disabled during debugging, I find that the method `initForOtherTemplate` is **not** being executed when the parameter is assigned.  `anotherTemplate.xhtml` **still** needs to do something with the parameter before the method will be executed.  That's what I was hoping to avoid.